# Select all fields from a collection, sorted by lowest field value and "grouped" by distinct field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection `scores` with the following fields

```
┬────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ player │ score │   mode   │
┼────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│  'A'   │   7   │  'easy'  │
│  'A'   │  11   │ 'medium' │
│  'A'   │  12   │  'hard'  │
│  'B'   │   9   │  'hard'  │
│  'B'   │  10   │  'easy'  │
│  'B'   │  10   │ 'medium' │
│  'C'   │   6   │ 'medium' │
│  'C'   │   9   │  'easy'  │
│  'C'   │  13   │  'hard'  │
┴────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

I want to select all the smallest scores `by player` so the expected result would be:

```
┬────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ player │ score │   mode   │
┼────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│  'A'   │   7   │  'easy'  │
│  'B'   │   9   │  'hard'  │
│  'C'   │   6   │ 'medium' │
┴────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

Also, I want to keep the document original structure in order to load the expected result as mongoose objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework to:

1. [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) the collection on the player then the score
2. Use the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage to group by player, and grab the [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) entry on each group
3. [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to the necessary output format
4. Optionally [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) on the player

For example, here's the collection based on your example:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id": 2, "player": "A", "score": 12, "mode": "hard" }
{ "_id": 0, "player": "A", "score": 7, "mode": "easy" }
{ "_id": 1, "player": "A", "score": 11, "mode": "medium" }
{ "_id": 3, "player": "B", "score": 9, "mode": "hard" }
{ "_id": 4, "player": "B", "score": 10, "mode": "easy" }
{ "_id": 5, "player": "B", "score": 10, "mode": "medium" }
{ "_id": 6, "player": "C", "score": 6, "mode": "medium" }
{ "_id": 7, "player": "C", "score": 9, "mode": "easy" }
{ "_id": 8, "player": "C", "score": 13, "mode": "hard" }
```

Aggregating using the workflow above:

```
db.test.aggregate([

  {$sort: {player: 1, score: 1}},

  {$group: { _id: '$player', 
             player: {$first:'$player'},
             score: {$first:'$score'}, 
             mode: {$first:'$mode'} }},

  {$project: { _id: 0 }},

  {$sort: {player: 1}}

])
```

Output is:

```
{ "player": "A", "score": 7, "mode": "easy" }
{ "player": "B", "score": 9, "mode": "hard" }
{ "player": "C", "score": 6, "mode": "medium" }
```

If you have a large collection, please make sure that you have an [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) with the specification of `{player: 1, score: 1}`.

Comment: Thank you!

Only one last question: my collection has ~30 fields and I need all of them populated. Is there any way to project all of them without writing one by one in the `$project` object?

Comment: Unfortunately as far as I know there's no way to shortcut it. It's very likely that all 30 fields would need to be present in the $group and the $project stage.

Comment: I take that back. I edited the $group so that it also capture the player, so in the $project stage you can just remove the _id field. However, you'll still need to have all the required fields in the $group stage. I don't think that can be avoided.